# Linq to Sql : Database changes in a Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I'm new to C# and Visual studio.I have the code for a C# Project on Visual Studio that is perfectly working. But, I need to make few changes to the database and code.Delete two columns - Col1,Col2 from Table A, add them to Table B and change the business logic accordingly . I have a .dbml file that defines the mapping between the database tables and the code. Is designer.cs files auto-generated from .dbml files while building the code ? If no, how do I generate these files ? If I were to delete the columns in Table - what are the corresponding files(dbml/designer.cs) I need to change ? This might be naive but, I'm not sure  how these files are connected to the database.

Comment: Right click the DBML and regenerate the model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, modify your SQL database.

Then open your .dbml file in design mode in Visual Studio. Select the tables in design mode that you want to update and delete.
Then drag the tables from server explorer and drop into .dbml file.

Finally, rebuild your project.